# Flexbox creates blank space on the right of a page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Whenever i remove the flex display- it goes away. Can't understand what's happening there. Been going through source up and down, but no element seems to be stretching there.

html of it

```
<div class="newheadwrap">
<div class="newlogo newhead">with contents</div>
<div class="newtagline newhead" >with contents</div>
<div class="mainhead newhead">with contents</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.newheadwrap {
-o-display:flex;
-webkit-display:flex;
-ms-display:flex;
-moz-display:flex;
display:flex;  
flex-direction:row;
width:966px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.newlogo {
width:17%;
padding-top:43px;
}
.newtagline {
width:33%;  
color:white;
padding-top:93px;
font-family: berkeleyFont;
font-size:16px;
float:right !important;
}
.mainhead {
width:50%;
}
```

I know it's not advised to post live links here, but fiddle will not do in this case, so, here is a link
https://aps-direct.myshopify.com

Comment: add overflow: hidden; to .newheadwrap and it will remove the extra space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to remove the extra padding to the right side of your current page:

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.newheadwrap`

```
.newheadwrap {
-o-display: flex;
-webkit-display: flex;
-ms-display: flex;
-moz-display: flex;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: 966px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

You have extra space because of this:

```
.span9 {
width: 717px;
}
```

reduce the width and it will fit

Comment: i did before, but it's messing up responsive part later. Just stands still like something has a fixed pixel width there.

Comment: Extra space because of .span9 {
width: 717px;
}